# Reshape and combine data from long to wide format with R

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape2, tidyr

I have data which looks like this:-

```
Customer.Name  Posting.Date  SKU Sales.Amount($)    
A         20150124    SKU1     12345  
B         20150125    SKU2     22345 
A         20150124    SKU3     52345  
A         20150125    SKU4     55345  
C         20150126    SKU6     62345  
B         20150127    SKU7     72345  
C         20150126    SKU8     72945
```

I'm trying to convert it into the following structures without column names:-
Interim Data Structure:-

```
A         20150124    SKU1     SKU 3  
A         20150125    SKU4     
B         20150125    SKU2 
C         20150126    SKU6     SKU8  
B         20150127    SKU7
```

The interim output is sorted by posting date and each SKU purchased as part of a customer level transaction (identified by customer name + posting date) needs to get converted to a column.

Final data structure (below) needs to just contains SKUs purchased in transactions with the customer name and posting date columns removed from the interim output above.

```
SKU1     SKU3 
SKU4
SKU2   
SKU6     SKU8 
SKU7
```

I have tried the following code to get the final structure but am getting an error.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
Dataset2 <- Data %>% 
group_by(Customer.Name, Posting.Date) %>%
summarise(SKU=toString(unique(SKU))) %>% 
select(Customer.Name, Posting.Date,SKU) %>%
spread(Customer.Name,SKU,drop=FALSE)
```

The error I get is

> Error: Each variable must be named. Problem variables: 2

Could you please guide on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Final data structure required is as follows:

Comment: Please remove the`($)` from the column name.  It works fine for me

Answer (score 1):

Here's one attempt. It has column names, though they can be discarded later as needed.

```
df <- data.frame(
  V1=c(     "A",      "B",      "A",      "A",      "C",      "B",      "C" ),
  V2=c(20150124, 20150125, 20150124, 20150125, 20150126, 20150127, 20150126 ),
  V3=c(  "SKU1",   "SKU2",   "SKU3",   "SKU4",   "SKU6",   "SKU7",   "SKU8" ),
  V4=c(   12345,    22345,    52345,    55345,    62345,    72345,    72945 ),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

I'm inferring from your question that the fourth column is unnecessary, so I remove it.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

out1 <- df %>%
  select(-V4) %>%
  group_by(V1, V2) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  spread(row, V3) %>%
  ungroup()
out1
# # A tibble: 5 × 4
#      V1       V2   `1`   `2`
# * <chr>    <dbl> <chr> <chr>
# 1     A 20150124  SKU1  SKU3
# 2     A 20150125  SKU4  <NA>
# 3     B 20150125  SKU2  <NA>
# 4     B 20150127  SKU7  <NA>
# 5     C 20150126  SKU6  SKU8

out1 %>% select(-V1, -V2)
# # A tibble: 5 × 2
#     `1`   `2`
# * <chr> <chr>
# 1  SKU1  SKU3
# 2  SKU4  <NA>
# 3  SKU2  <NA>
# 4  SKU7  <NA>
# 5  SKU6  SKU8
```

Comment: Could you please "accept" the answer? (It's good etiquette on SO. Look for the checkmark to the left of the answer.)

Answer (score 0):

It is better to have column names without special characters.  If we remove it

```
colnames(Data)[4] <- "Sales.Amount"
```

The OP's code works fine

```
Dataset2
# A tibble: 4 × 4
#  Posting.Date          A     B          C
#*         <int>      <chr> <chr>      <chr>
#1     20150124 SKU1, SKU3  <NA>       <NA>
#2     20150125       SKU4  SKU2       <NA>
#3     20150126       <NA>  <NA> SKU6, SKU8 
#4     20150127       <NA>  SKU7       <NA>
```

Or even with it, it works fine on `tidyr_0.6.0` and `dplyr_0.5.0`

Comment: Thanks for the response. The code did not work for me after changing the variable name.

Comment: @Sai I am not sure about the case as I don't have any problem with your example.  What is the version of `dplyr` and `tidyr`.  I posted the versions that I use